# Is there a way to export a list of all links within an excel document

Tags: excel, vba

As part of an automation project I am automating the updating of values within an excel file. There are multiple files to be updated and each of these has links to other files, usually links to around 20 files.

In order to streamline automation and optimise the process I need a list of all files each of the "documents to be updated" links to.

Is there a macro I can use other tool to export a list of links within an excel file. Even just printing it to somewhere within the excel file itself would be useful and allow me to map links across all files.

For clarity:
There are many formulas that reference external workbooks.
An example of one such formula:

```
VLOOKUP($D$7,'C:\DATA\[BalanceSheet-LevelsFlows-VO-M.xlsx]Position'!$A$1:$HA$9999,F4,FALSE)
```

There are more than 36000 formulas referencing external workbooks in one file. There are references to 8 external workbooks.

My aim is to get a list of these external workbooks.

Whilst it would be fast to do it manually in this instance I have over 30 of the files I need to list external references for and some of these reference over 30 external workbooks.

This is a one off process for mapping, it doesn't need to be elegant, just quicker than doing it manually.

Comment: Do you mean Hyperlinks (where the user can click on) or references to other workbooks in formulas?

Comment: References to other workbooks in formulas.

Comment: Could you share some examples of what can be found in the formulas and what you would like to return? Where exactly would this list be exported to?

Comment: Is there a specific naming standard that is being followed that would possibly allow you to perform a `find` (look in formulas) command?

Comment: There is code around (eg http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=409) that creates a sheet with all formulas of a workbook. Execute it and set a filter to show only formulas that contain a filename (eg `.xls`)

Comment: @FunThomasthis works, but requires so much processing after filtering (removing everything in the formula except the file path) that it's probably quicker to copy manually from the update links window in excel.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I've added some extra information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Link Sources

- [`LinkSources method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.linksources)
- [`XlLink enumeration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllink)

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testLinkSources()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = getLinkSources(wb)
    If Not IsEmpty(Data) Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add
        ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Data)).Value = Data
    End If
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = LinkSourcesToArray(wb)
    If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then
        Debug.Print Join(arr, vbLf)
    End If
End Sub

Function getLinkSources( _
    wb As Workbook) _
As Variant
    If Not IsEmpty(wb.LinkSources) Then
        Dim arr() As Variant: arr = wb.LinkSources
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(arr)
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
        Dim r As Long
        For r = 1 To rCount
            Data(r, 1) = arr(r)
        Next r
        getLinkSources = Data
    End If
End Function

Function LinkSourcesToArray( _
    wb As Workbook) _
As Variant
    If Not IsEmpty(wb.LinkSources) Then
        LinkSourcesToArray = wb.LinkSources
    End If
End Function
```