# How to find a list of excel sheets which contain references to one specific excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet I would like to move to a new folder directory, but its an old historical file with probably 20+ different excel sheets being linked to it. I would like to generate a list of all files which contain references to this file. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66491859) what you're looking for?

Comment: I think this is a great starting point! However, I am interested in what files may be referencing a particular excel workbook. Lets call my main workbook Test.xlsx. Its found in Folder A. Within Folder A are 20 other excel workbooks, some of which may reference Test.xlsx. I see I can use this code to open up a workbook of my choosing to pull from there the list of references excel sheets within it. However, is there a way I can open all 20 excel sheets that are found within this file path, and have this code run on all of them, and produce their results in different tabs?

Comment: So you want the results in a new workbook in column `A` of `20` worksheets? Can the file names be used as (valid) worksheet names?

Comment: Yes correct! The file names may be too long for the worksheet names but ideally yes